# How to lock the form from further resizing with aspect ratio resizing

Tags: vb.net, resize, flicker, aspect-ratio

I currently use this code and it works flawlessly

<s>My question is how do I modify the `WndProc` to stop at my preferred limit of Width and Height.</s> Okay I solved that by setting the `MinimumSize`, but a new problem arises when the aspect ratio of the form reaches the limit of the windows desktop `maximum right` size it starts to mess up the aspect ratio starts streching instead of locking up.

Need to somehow fix the `WndProc` with `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width` to stop increasing both sizes when the limit Width is hit.

I added this which works but it's still only for my resolution how do I make it universal to support all resolutions.

```
        If r.right - r.left > SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width Then
            r.bottom = 900 'quick fix (not good) how to calculate this value?
        End If
```

source of code:
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_form_fixed_aspect.html

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
...
Public Structure Rect
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
End Structure

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As _
    System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Static first_time As Boolean = True
    Static aspect_ratio As Double
    Const WM_SIZING As Long = &H214
    Const WMSZ_LEFT As Integer = 1
    Const WMSZ_RIGHT As Integer = 2
    Const WMSZ_TOP As Integer = 3
    Const WMSZ_TOPLEFT As Integer = 4
    Const WMSZ_TOPRIGHT As Integer = 5
    Const WMSZ_BOTTOM As Integer = 6
    Const WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT As Integer = 7
    Const WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT As Integer = 8

    If m.Msg = WM_SIZING And m.HWnd.Equals(Me.Handle) Then
        ' Turn the message's lParam into a Rect.
        Dim r As Rect
        r = DirectCast( _
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, _
                GetType(Rect)), _
            Rect)

        ' The first time, save the form's aspect ratio.
        If first_time Then
            first_time = False
            aspect_ratio = (r.bottom - r.top) / (r.right - _
                r.left)
        End If

        ' Get the current dimensions.
        Dim wid As Double = r.right - r.left
        Dim hgt As Double = r.bottom - r.top

        ' Enlarge if necessary to preserve the aspect ratio.
        If hgt / wid > aspect_ratio Then
            ' It's too tall and thin. Make it wider.
            wid = hgt / aspect_ratio
        Else
            ' It's too short and wide. Make it taller.
            hgt = wid * aspect_ratio
        End If

        ' See if the user is dragging the top edge.
        If m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_TOP Or _
           m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_TOPLEFT Or _
           m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_TOPRIGHT _
        Then
            ' Reset the top.
            r.top = r.bottom - CInt(hgt)
        Else
            ' Reset the height to the saved value.
            r.bottom = r.top + CInt(hgt)
        End If

        ' See if the user is dragging the left edge.
        If m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_LEFT Or _
           m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_TOPLEFT Or _
           m.WParam.ToInt32 = WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT _
        Then
            ' Reset the left.
            r.left = r.right - CInt(wid)
        Else
            ' Reset the width to the saved value.
            r.right = r.left + CInt(wid)
        End If

        ' Update the Message object's LParam field.
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(r, m.LParam, True)
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out user's desktop resolution with `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right`

Comment: Yeah `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width` works just as well. Problem is how do I fix the code above to lock up when it hit the limit? because it starts resizing without keeping aspect when one of the limits is triggered, well mostly the width limit, but height could probably also screw up in some rare occurrence.